# request url with number increase

Tags: python, web-crawler

I would like to request a website URL that is similar to this:

```
page = requests.get('www.google.com/page')
```

After the first page there is that number starts from 1 and goes on. Is there a simple way to add the number to the page or do I need to create a dictionary with all the numbers?

I have tried this so far with no success:

```
number=1
page = requests.get('http://www.google.com/page' + number+=1 + '')
```

Can anyone tell me a better way to do this other then making a dictionary?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

After re-reviewing your question, I think this is what you're trying to
accomplish:

```
# Page begins without a number suffix.
number = None
while True:
    # Determine URL.
    url = 'http://www.google.com/page'
    if number is not None:
        # Don't add number suffix for first page.
        url += str(number) 

    # Request page.
    page = requests.get(url)

    # Handle page.
    # ...
    if done_handling_pages:
        break

    # Increment number for next page.
    if number is None:
        # The starting number for the second page.
        number = 1 
    else:
        # Increment page number by 1 after second page.
        number += 1
```

---

### Original Answer

First you need to determine if the starting page number is `1` or `0`:

```
start_number = 0
# OR
start_number = 1
```

Then try this:

```
for number in range(start_number, max_number + start_number):
    page = requests.get('http://www.google.com/page' + str(number))
```

Where `max_number` is the maximum number to go up to.

Or if you want to count up indefinitely until you reach a custom condition, you can do:

```
import itertools
for number in itertools.count(start_number):
    page = requests.get('http://www.google.com/page' + str(number))
    # Logic handling page result.
    # ...
    if done_handling_pages:
        break
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to start with 1 and not with 0. Maybe you could amplify that `xrange` is 0-based.

Comment: i tried with the first post but i think it starts from 0 which give me page not found, the second one will take long to do because there is no limit and it will keep searching

Comment: @blueinc I've updated my answer because I think I see now what you're trying to do.